# How to call Kotlin copy() from data class to java class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Suppose I have a data class and want to use copy() and call it in java class.

In kotlin we do like this

`data class User(val name: String = "", val age: Int = 0)`

`fun copy(name: String = this.name, age: Int = this.age) = User(name, age)`

```
val jack = User(name = "Jack", age = 1)
val olderJack = jack.copy(age = 2)`
```

But in java we can't.

One method is to create copy method in data class and call it in java class using `sampleClassObject.copy(...)`.

But the problem is suppose there are total `5 parameters in constructor` and I only want to `pass 2 parameters using copy()` in java class how to do that?

Comment: I think you can do it only by `set` methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin data class copy function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620782/kotlin-data-class-copy-function-not-working)

Answer (score 7):

The reason why `copy()` is so useful in Kotlin are named arguments, which allow you to selectively specify only the parameters you need.

In Java, this feature does not exist, so people try to achieve the same using a different paradigm: **builders**.

By defining a builder in the Kotlin class (unfortunately we cannot use `set` properties, because they cannot return `this`):

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int) {
    class Builder(origin: User) {
        private var name: String = origin.name
        private var age: Int = origin.age

        // also performs operations on 'this' and returns 'this'
        fun name(value: String) = this.also { name = value }
        fun age(value: Int) = this.also { age = value }

        fun build() = User(name, age)
    }
}
```

You could then do something like this:

```
User user = new User(...);

User copied = new User.Builder(user)
   .name("Alfred")
   .build();
```

If you need extra syntactic sugar, you can always add more methods:

```
// Kotlin
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int) {
    ...
    fun copy() = Builder(this)
}

// Java
User copied = user.copy().name("Alfred").build()
```

Note that projects such as [Lombok](https://www.projectlombok.org/features/Builder) can automatically generate a lot of the boilerplate needed.

Comment: Earlier my project is using `autovalue` but now we have converted to data class and want to use Kotlin copy().

Comment: If you want to call Kotlin's built-in `copy()` from Java, you have to provide all arguments. This makes it not very useful, as you could directly construct a new object.

Comment: Yeah, you are right but the situation is like that. So, how can use copy() in java to pass less parameter than actual constructor? As we use copy() in order to update few parameters.

Comment: As I said, **you can't**. I wrote my answer to show you an alternative way of specifying only the arguments you need :)

Comment: By the way, if you cannot modify the existing Kotlin classes: you don't need to. You can easily declare the builder class in a separate file. You can even write the builder in Java and possibly combine it with Lombok.

Comment: Okay, I will try to implement that. Is there any way to override Koltin copy() and use according to our requirement?

Comment: @PrafulRanjan Only for a specific set of parameters as in Phát Phát's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is because Kotlin does supports **default parameters** Java doesn't.
But you can do following.

> In Java

```
User user = new User().copy("Your Name", 10);
System.out.println(user.copy().getName());
```

> In Kotlin

```
data class User(val name: String = "", val age: Int = 0){
fun copy() = User(name, age)
```

> Keep coding. Keep learning :)
>       }

Comment: I appreciate that you replied, but my question is little different.

Comment: If you want to do it in Java you have to override a method n number of times as Java doesn't support default parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this can be used in the real use case, but this might be helpful.

This is `User` class:

```
data class User(val param1: String = "",
                val param2: String = "",
                val param3: String = "",
                val param4: String = "",
                val param5: String = "") {
    constructor(param1: String, param2: String) : this(param1, param2,
            "This is optional 1",
            "This is optional 2",
            "This is optional 3")

    fun copy(param1: String, param2: String) = User(param1, param2)
}
```

This is how to make use of it inside `java` class:

```
    User user = new User("a", "b").copy("c", "d");
```

By default, you don't need to do this, data class already has a copy() function

> Deriving a data class from a type that already had a copy(...) function with a matching signature is deprecated in Kotlin 1.2 and will be prohibited in Kotlin 1.3.

[Data class defination](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

Comment: but if we use constructor like this in data class there is some error message `There's a cycle in delegation calls chain`. How to fix that?